# Correlation with binary response and Likert scale response

Tags: correlation, mean, likert, binary-data

I have 4 data groups:
- 3 groups from a 5-point Likert scale (1 ~ 5)
- 1 group is binary (Incorrect/Correct -- converted to 0, 1)

I have performed Pearson's r and Spearman's rho with the Likert responses easily enough and they appear to be related to a scatterplot. However, the binary data is giving some strange numbers that don't appear to be showing a true relationship (I'm new to using SPSS so this may be the problem).

An alternative I want advice on in the comparison of means. I am aware of paired t-tests but I don't know if they are suitable or if something else is better suited. 
I'm especially interested in the relationship between, e.g. a) Perception of x= M:3.12, b) Realisation of x= M:3.95

Comment: I don't entirely follow your question. You may find it helpful to read this blog post: [how to ask a statistics question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/). Regarding your question about whether binary responses should be coded as {0,1}, or {1,5}, it will not make any difference--you can try it for yourself & see.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my original question and shifted the focus to a comparison of means, as in a paired t-test or an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare two groups on three different Likert scales, each scored 1 to 5, you probably want three ordinal logistic regressions, each with a Likert scale as the dependent variable and the group as the independent variable.

I do not know how to do ordinal logistic in SPSS, but it surely can be done.